# How do I create a new directory at the location of an existing file? 

Tags: java, file

I'm fairly new to Java so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Basically, a file is a song. I'm using JFileChooser to select multiple songs. I then do some stuff with the array of songs (their file names and paths). I want to then create 2 directories inside the directory in which the songs are located, a directory for the artist name, and a directory for the album name inside the artist name directory. I then want to move the files in my array to the album directory.

I'm fairly sure I'm supposed to be using mkdirs() method.

How can I tell the program to make the directories in the location of the songs whose paths I have stored in an array of files? I can only find examples of getting rid of the extension, not the file name, to be able to use the path for the mkdirs() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have some `File foo` that points to `c:\foo\bar\baz\music.wav`, to get the parent directory you can use [`File.getParentFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29). I recommend constructing the subdirectories using the `File` constructor:

```
File subdir1 = new File(foo.getParentFile(), "mysubdir1");
if(!subdir1.exists()){
    subdir1.mkdirs();
}
```

Since you're sure that `subdir1`'s parent exists, you can get away calling `subdir1.mkdir()` instead, but you won't lose anything by calling `mkdirs`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for one of the [getParent()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29) functions.